# How to configure svn to cloak some directories?

Tags: svn, version-control, tfs, cloaking

There is a nice feature in TFS called cloaking. In this feature, a developer can can determine which folders NOT to be copied in the working folder while checking out the sources. Can Svn support such a thing or not?

Comment: You really mean file that are in the repository, but that will not be checked out ? (so they can be pushed, but are kind of non-accessible after it)... because else I would have talked about ignoring files, but that the other way around...

Comment: Yes, files are in repository, but should not be checked-out. They could be substituted by files from other repositories using svn:externals. Take a look at cloak feature at TFS. That is really useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use permissions to hide parts of the repository from certain people, but as far as working copy configuration, no SVN doesn't support anything like that.

Comment: Event if he create a pre-checkout hook or something like it ?

Comment: @FMaz008 You could probably achieve something like that with a hook, but again that's only on the server, and not something the client has control over.

Answer (score 2):

Old question but I found this to work: (as found on http://svn.haxx.se/tsvnusers/archive-2006-06/0020.shtml)

Just switch each directory to svn://server/empty, like this:

```
for i in boring* dull stupid etc 
do svn switch svn://server/empty $i 
done
```

This will delete all the versioned files in those directories, and thenceforth, doing "svn up" will *not* bring them back.
To bring them back, just switch them back to where they were originally:

```
for i in boring* dull stupid etc 
do svn switch svn://server/trunk/$i $i 
done
```